# Should I free memory in C if it is not allocated properly?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

when declaring for example a malloc and then checking if it is NULL to see if it has been properly allocated, should I free the memory if it is null, example:

```
int *p;
p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); 
  
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        free(p); //Should I free here or will it create an error?
        return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: Just a side-note: in the case when `p == NULL` ... `free(p);` and `free(NULL);` are equivalent (C passes arguments by value) and well-behaved (they do nothing).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) returns a null pointer it has failed to allocate anything at all, and there's nothing to free.

With that said, passing a null pointer to [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) does nothing, so it's safe.

On a related note, in C you shouldn't really [cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 1):

> Should I free memory in C if it is not allocated properly?

You shouldn't, because you can't, because it turns out the question doesn't even make sense.

`malloc` either gives you a pointer to properly-allocated memory, or it doesn't.
Those two cases are distinct: It either gives you a non-null pointer, or a null pointer.
A null pointer return means that `malloc` failed, and did not allocate any memory for you.

Suppose that in the process of trying but failing to allocate the memory that you asked for, `malloc` did partially allocate some memory, or something.  Suppose it was your job to free this.  How would you do this?  You have no way of referring to that memory!  When `malloc` fails, it returns you a null pointer, and a null pointer points, by definition, nowhere.

It doesn't make much sense to pass a null pointer to the `free` function.  Once upon a time, this was an error, and tended to crash.  Today, it's harmless: `free` checks to see if you've handed it a null pointer, and if so, it quietly does nothing.

So in fact, if `malloc` partially allocates memory or something, then fails, it has to be `malloc`'s job to clean that up automatically, before returning the null pointer to you.